# Copying Visual Studio C++ projects between non-networked computers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-vista, windows-7-x64, projects-and-solutions

I would like to easily copy and update Visual Studio (2010) C++ projects from my business computer to my home computer.  Due to slow network access with remote access and FTP, copying data onto a thumb drive and driving home is faster.

I would like to only copy the files that changed from the business computer to thumb drive and then copy from thumb drive to home computer.  Also vice-versa:  copy only files that changed from home computer to thumb drive, then from thumb drive to business computer.

Accessing the project directly from the thumb drive is incredibly slow, especially with Intellisense.

I don't need to copy the temporary files, such as object files.

I've tried using `Make` from the command line, but it has an issue with same file names but different drive letters.

Another caveat is that my business computer is Windows 7 64-bit, and my home computer is Vista Home edition.

Preferences are for {free} Visual Studio tools, then free utilities.

If you feel this is not a good post for StackOverflow, please migrate to a better site.

**Edit 1: Different folder layouts**
The "root" path of the projects is different.
Windows 7 -- /Users/tmatthews
Windows Vista -- /Users/Thomas/Work

Comment: Have you looked at visual studio online http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-online-overview-vs.aspx

Comment: I'm trying to imagine just how slow the network must be that copying <32GB to a USB and driving home is faster...

Comment: Unrelated, there are usually legal issues here to address.

Comment: @MooingDuck: It doesn't have to be very slow to lose on a 32GB transfer.  More normal project sizes of ~50MB though, it's difficult for the network to lose.

Comment: Oh, I guess 32GB at 5M/s is 53 minutes, that's a bit higher than I expected.

Comment: @MooingDuck: The company doesn't have high speed network connections to its FTP server.  The Remote Connection from my house to work is unreliable as I get "interruption" notices, even though we both use the same ISP!

Comment: @MooingDuck:  Commute time is under 20 minutes.  So, by your calculations, I have time to stop off and get coffee before the data arrives. :-)

Comment: @MarkHall:  I have this incredible distrust of using a Microsoft cloud server, especially where Intellectual Property is concerned.  Microsoft may claim that it has rights to everything stored on its server.  Also, my project is private and can't afford to have the technology leak out on a cloud server.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I used calculations based on a large thumbdrive and a slow personal internet.  Using average thumbdrive and average US personal internet is merely 5 minutes.

Comment: @ThomasMathews  I can understand that and appreciate your feelings on that, was mainly pointing it out because of it being a source control server and once you got past the initial upload you should be just working with the files that were changed.

Comment: Visual Studio Online is most likely much more secure than your office's FTP server :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using a version control like git. If your network is slow it may take a while the first time, then subsequent updates should be fast as only the changes will be transferred.

You could also just setup a GIT repo on your thumb drive and update to/from that repo on your work and home computers so as not have to copy all of the files every time. It doesn't have to go over the network, though you will likely have a much greater degree of integrity with regards to the actual version control using a network solution.

Comment: The problem with GIT is that it copies files when it makes full tree backups, which fills up a thumb drive.  Other version control systems store the most recent version uncompressed and compress other copies.

Comment: There is that. You should research the options depending on which route you take. Disk space has never been a concern of mine with regards to version control, so I can't really recommend a specific product if that is an issue. But I would definitely recommend SOME version control regardless.

Comment: One day you will make changes at one location and forget to bring the thumb drive or forget to transfer the files at the other location before making changes there, and you will have to reconcile them. This is typically trivial with source control, not so much without it.

Answer (score 0):

XCOPY the changed files and move on with your life.

at work
**xcopy /EXCLUDE:EXCLUDE.TXT      /Y /I /E /R /D  /C c:\users\tmatthews   d:\usbfolder**

at home
**xcopy /EXCLUDE:EXCLUDE.TXT      /Y /I /E /R /D  /C  d:\usbfolder  c:\users\thomas\work**

basically reverse the order to take the files back to work.

I have used this technique for years to duplicate the changed files on my desktop on to the file server so the files are in two places.

Comment: might mention the /D flag

Comment: I'd rather have something that could list the changed files, then use XCOPY on the changed files.

Comment: The problem with just copying files is having to reconcile the case - which will inevitably happen - where you have outstanding changes at both locations because you forgot to transfer the files before working. It can still be done with diff tools, but a good source control solution will handle most of it for you automatically, and is especially trivial with a visual tool like TortoiseGIT/TortoiseSVN.